# Calculate the $P\left(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\leq1\right)$

Tags: probability

I got the following question:

> Let $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)}$ be statistic order of three independent random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ with uniform distribution in $(0,1)$. Find the $P\left(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}\leq1\right)$.

In the solution they got:

[image]

I'm trying to figure why it's true. I'm familiar with the trick:
$$
f_{X_{(1)}X_{(2)}}(x,y)\cdot dxdy=P\left(x\leq X_{(1)}\leq x+dx,y\leq X_{(2)}\leq y+dy\right)
$$
But how did they got the result?

Comment: It is just a multinomial argument. $(X_{(1)} = x, X_{(2)} = y)$ is equivalent to say that we have $0$ $X_i$ on $(0, x)$, $1$ at $x$, $0$ on $(x, y)$, $1$ at $y$ and $1$ on $(y, 1)$. So we have $\displaystyle f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}}(x,y)dxdy = \frac {3!} {0!1!0!1!1!} F(x)^0 [f(x)dx]^1 [F(y) - F(x)]^0 [f(y)dy]^1 [1 - F(y)]^1$

Answer (score 1):

If $(X_n)$ is a sequence of i.i.d. $U(0,1)$ random variables, then for $i<j$ the joint density of $(X_{(i)},X_{(j)})$ is
$$
f_{(i),(j)}(s,t) = n!\frac{s^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}\frac{(t-s)^{j-i-1}}{(j-i-1)!}\frac{(1-t)^{n-j}}{(n-j)!}\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{0<s<t<1\}}.
$$
So we have
$$
f_{(1),(2)}(s,t) = 6(1-t)\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{0<s<t<1\}}.
$$
It follows that the density of $X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}$ is
\begin{align}
f_{(1)+(2)}(t) &= \int_{\mathbb R}f_{(1),(2)}(s,t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \left(\int_0^{\frac t2}6(1-(t-s))\ \mathsf ds\right)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t)+ \left(\int_{t-1}^{\frac t2}6(1-(t-s))\ \mathsf ds\right)\mathsf 1_{(1,2)}(t)\\
&= 3t\left(1-\frac34t\right)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t) + \frac{3}{4} (2-t)^2\mathsf 1_{(1,2)}(t).
\end{align}
We compute the desired probability by integrating this density over $(0,1)$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}<1) &= \int_{(0,1)}f_{(1)+(2)}(t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^13t\left(1-\frac34t\right)\ \mathsf dt\\
&=\frac34.
\end{align}

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have corrected the answer.